# How to write this SQL query for a XML type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml

I am using SQL Server 2012 in which I have a table `[abc]` which  has  a column called `[Information]` of the [XML] type.

This column has values like -

```
<Information>
  <Groups>
    <Group Name="Monitor">
      <Items>
        <Item>
          <Name>Cid</Name>
          <Value>2323232323</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Name>Tid</Name>
          <Value>6656565656</Value>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </Group>
  </Groups>
</Information>
```

How can I write a SQL Query which can query this column and further extract the value `[Tid]` ?

Comment: The *‘extract the value [Tid]’* bit is confusing. What is it that you want to return, the string `Tid` or the contents of the `Value` tag where `Name` is `Tid`?

Answer (score 10):

What you want here is not entirely clear from your question. My guess is that you want the value from the `<Value>` node where the `<Name>` node is `Tid`.

Shred the XML using the `nodes()` function on `/Information/Groups/Group/Items/Item` and add a predicate `[Name/text()="Tid"]` to check the value for `<Name>`.

```
declare @T table(X xml not null);
insert into @T(X) values
('<Information>
  <Groups>
    <Group Name="Monitor">
      <Items>
        <Item>
          <Name>Cid</Name>
          <Value>2323232323</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Name>Tid</Name>
          <Value>6656565656</Value>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </Group>
  </Groups>
</Information>');

select I.X.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'bigint') as Value
from @T as T
  cross apply T.X.nodes('/Information/Groups/Group/Items/Item[Name/text()="Tid"]') as I(X);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you only need `<Name>Tid</Name>`, your query would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML = N'
<Information>
  <Groups>
    <Group Name="Monitor">
      <Items>
        <Item>
          <Name>Cid</Name>
          <Value>2323232323</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Name>Tid</Name>
          <Value>6656565656</Value>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </Group>
  </Groups>
</Information>
';

DECLARE @x_table TABLE (x XML);
INSERT @x_table ( x )
VALUES ( @x );

SELECT      ca.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(3)')
FROM        @x_table AS x
CROSS APPLY x.x.nodes('/Information/Groups/Group/Items/Item/Name/text()') AS ca(c)
WHERE       ca.c.exist('. [.="Tid"]') = 1;
```

If you need something else, let me know.